# How to detect when FMX List View is scrolled to the bottom?

Tags: listview, delphi, scroll, firemonkey

I'm working on a Firemonkey `TListView` to display search results. This list loads 25 items at a time, but could potentially show hundreds of items.

I need to detect when the user has scrolled down to the bottom, so that I can fetch the next 25 items to show in the list. However, I cannot find the appropriate properties to determine this.

There's the `OnPullRefresh` event, but that applies to scrolling to the top of the list and pulling it down. What I need is similar, but for the *bottom* of the list instead of the *top*.

There's the `OnScrollViewChange` event, which seems appropriate. There's also the `ScrollViewPos` property, which is also useful. However, I cannot figure out what to compare that number to - specifically, the maximum possible value for `ScrollViewPos`. Something like `ScrollViewMax` is what I would need.

But I cannot find anything more to accurately detect that user has scrolled to the bottom.

How can I detect when a user has scrolled to the bottom of a Firemonkey `TListView` so that I can load more search results?

**EDIT**

If this is not possible for whatever reason, there is an alternative to add a dummy item to the end of the list with a "Load More..." button. But I'd rather it be automated.

**EDIT2**

I forgot to mention... I have the Search Box showing in this list view, and items can have a variable height. If calculating this based on item contents is the only way, then such a calculation needs to be *perfect*. I don't want to know when user is "approaching" or "near" the bottom, but when user exactly hits the bottom of the list.

Comment: Ok, then look at the source of `ScrollTo` method that scrolls to a specific item.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Further investigation I found the following in

```
function TListViewBase.GetItemRect(const AItemIndex: Integer): TRectF;
```

If you go deeper in

```
function TListViewBase.GetItemRelRect(const Index: Integer; const LocRect: TRectF;
  const SideSpace: Integer = 0): TRectF;
```

then you will realize that the last item's Top is

```
listview1.GetItemRect(listview1.ItemCount-1).top+listview1.ScrollViewPos-listview1.SideSpace-listview1.LocalRect.top
```

whatever was your items variable height. This represents the value of `FHeightSums[Index]` which is a list containing the sum of height till the item with Index `Index`

**Now to the problem:** *You want the calculation to be perfect. you want a touch down.*

And this is it

```
procedure TForm5.ListView1ScrollViewChange(Sender: TObject);
var
Tmp_top : single;
begin
Tmp_top := listview1.GetItemRect(listview1.ItemCount-1).top+listview1.ScrollViewPos-listview1.SideSpace-listview1.LocalRect.top;

if Tmp_top+listview1.GetItemRect(listview1.ItemCount-1).height-listview1.Height=listview1.ScrollViewPos-2*listview1.SideSpace then
    showmessage('touch down');

end;
```

**Edit:** if you further simplify this formula you will end up in the other answer with few upgrades

```
 procedure TForm5.ListView1ScrollViewChange(Sender: TObject);
begin

if listview1.GetItemRect(listview1.ItemCount-1).bottom=listview1.Height-listview1.SideSpace then
    showmessage('touch down');

end;
```

now this will cover any changes in padding, margins, sidespace, searchbox visibility and searchbox size changing.

Comment: Won't work correctly if there's a search box or if items are a variable height (which I have both). Also not quite sure about margins / padding. This could be a much trickier formula, because I need it to match exactly.

Comment: @JerryDodge I just tested the search box and the formula is not affected. As for the item variable height it was not mentioned in the question. I think you should add that. However I will try to  find something better and get back to you

Comment: I haven't had a chance to try it yet, working on other non-visual stuff right now. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Jerry, Please let me know if you have found a non-visual stuff regarding to your question above.

Answer (score 3):

Try this code. Self-explanatory I think...

```
procedure TForm1.ListView1ScrollViewChange(Sender: TObject);
var
  R: TRectF;
begin
  if TListView(Sender).ItemCount > 0 then // Just in case...
  begin
    // Get the last item's Rect
    R := TListView(Sender).GetItemRect(TListView(Sender).ItemCount - 1);
    // Bottom?
    if R.Bottom = TListView(Sender).Height then
      Caption := 'Reached bottom!'
    else
      Caption := 'Bottom not reached yet.';
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I like this answer it is simpler and use only one call of `GetItemRect()`. However it will fail and not work if the side space changes, luckily I know how to fix this since my answer cover this :).  to overcome this change the if condition from `R.Bottom = TListView(Sender).Height` to `R.Bottom = TListView(Sender).Height - TListView(Sender).SideSpace` and it is done

Comment: Also the first if is unnecessary because there is a possibility of having seven or 15 items and the scroll bars will not be visible. It will only be visible when the items total height is bigger than the canvas height. As a conclusion the case where there is no items and scroll bars are showing is not possible(at least for this question)

Comment: I just noticed this. If I simplify my second formula I end up in your answer(of course with the modification I told you)