# Detect When TVertScrollBox bottom reached then do some procedure

Tags: android, ios, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.3-rio

I  have a `TVertScrollBox`  and a bunch of flow layouts that got generated on runtime over the scrollbox.. its an  app that load posts 
I want to load  10 new posts(layouts) whenever the user reach the `TVertScrollBox` bottom..

I tried using  `ViewportPositionChange` Event

```
//-scroll is a TVertScrollBox
 uses Math
procedure TForm1.scrollViewportPositionChange(Sender: TObject;
  const OldViewportPosition, NewViewportPosition: TPointF;
  const ContentSizeChanged: Boolean);

begin
if CompareValue(NewViewportPosition.Y,  scroll.Content.Height  ) = EqualsValue then
 begin
 ShowMessage('lets start loading new posts');
 end;
end;
```

the problem with this attempt is it only works when there is two flow layouts present on the VertScrollBox which  obviously means I am doing it wrong..

How can I achieve that correctly ?

Comment: [This might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46305721)