# Detect when Delphi FMX ListBox is scrolled to the bottom?

Tags: delphi, listbox, firemonkey

I need to detect when the user has scrolled down to the bottom in a ListBox , so that I can fetch the next 25 items to show in the listBox, Any Tip?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46306950/7579632 did you see this one? I think it is the same Idea.

Comment: ListBox and ListView have diferent properties , options, ListBox don't have that options...

Comment: I did not check the list box yet but if it has scrolltoControl() then what you need is in there.

Comment: scrolltoControl()?, ummm,  what is your idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay so let us break this down, first we go to [ScrollToItem](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/FMX.ListBox.TCustomListBox.ScrollToItem) in FMX.ListBox unit

```
procedure TCustomListBox.ScrollToItem(const Item: TListBoxItem);
begin
  if (Item <> nil) and (Content <> nil) and (ContentLayout <> nil) then
  begin
    if VScrollBar <> nil then
    begin
      if Content.Position.Y + Item.Position.Y + Item.Margins.Top + Item.Margins.Bottom + Item.Height >
        ContentLayout.Position.Y + ContentLayout.Height then
        VScrollBar.Value := VScrollBar.Value + (Content.Position.Y + Item.Position.Y + Item.Margins.Top +
          Item.Margins.Bottom + Item.Height - ContentLayout.Position.Y - ContentLayout.Height);
      if Content.Position.Y + Item.Position.Y < ContentLayout.Position.Y then
        VScrollBar.Value := VScrollBar.Value + Content.Position.Y + Item.Position.Y - ContentLayout.Position.Y;
    end;
    if HScrollBar <> nil then
    begin
      if Content.Position.X + Item.Position.X + Item.Margins.Left + Item.Margins.Right + Item.Width >
        ContentLayout.Position.X + ContentLayout.Width then
        HScrollBar.Value := HScrollBar.Value + (Content.Position.X + Item.Position.X + Item.Margins.Left +
          Item.Margins.Right + Item.Width - ContentLayout.Position.X - ContentLayout.Width);
      if Content.Position.X + Item.Position.X < 0 then
        HScrollBar.Value := HScrollBar.Value + Content.Position.X + Item.Position.X - ContentLayout.Position.X;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Now as you can see. the procedure checks for many values (margins, paddings, top, ....) and then moves `VScrollBar` by setting `VScrollBar.Value` to the appropriate position.

You want to know when the Vertical scroll bar has reached the bottom.

so we use the same idea as my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46305721) for the list view.

We first add this hack to expose the private and protected parts of TListBox class

```
TListBox = class(FMX.ListBox.TListBox)
  end;
```

add that to the form where the listbox is and then use the `VScrollChange(Sender: TObject);` event and reverse engineer the if conditions.

Something like this will work for you

```
procedure TForm1.ListBox1VScrollChange(Sender: TObject);
var
  S: Single;
begin
  S:= ListBox1.ContentRect.Height;

  if ListBox1.VScrollBar.ValueRange.Max = S + ListBox1.VScrollBar.Value then
    Caption := 'hit'
  else
    Caption := 'no hit';
end;
```

when trying to solve these types of problems always look for a ScrollToControl function and get the inspiration from there. The code above is working with simple items added to the scroll box. if you have any problems with margins or paddings just evolve the formula to cope with that.

Comment: amazing, but I noticed something, when you scroll with mouse it don't work...

Comment: I just tried it and you are right. apparently the  `VScrollChange` is not called when using the mouse wheel. but you can use the `MouseWheel` event with the same code and it will work.