# how to get listbox max position in firemonkey, delphi rio?

Tags: json, delphi, listbox, firemonkey, listitem

I need add more item when the listbox is in the last item.. I try use the OnViewportPositionChange event, but I couldn't check the end of the scroll

Sorry for my english.. I'm brazilian.

Comment: I just wrote an answer on how to see if the list box reached the end of scrolling. https://stackoverflow.com/a/62217054/7579632

Comment: Great! Your aswer solved my problem :D

Comment: Good to know that. have a nice day.